# Retrieve multiple value in one session

Tags: asp.net

when i add to cart
i using Session["Cart"] = new List() { Id }; which is get the id pass from the query string
but when i preview on the cartview event i add 2/3 product, it only will show 1 column, which is the latest. why it will replace? my code look like. how should i do to make sure every time i add it will be display on the view cart page? if this code problem or my cart preview page have probelm?

Comment: To use it in generic way try this http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/559508/Session-Management-With-Generics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example ,

```
string[] a = new string[]{"a","b","c"};
Session["values"] = a;
```

And  you can retrieve it like this.

```
 string[] a = (string[])Session["values"]
```

**using `List`**

```
Session["test"] = yourList;
```

And  you can retrieve it like this.

```
 var list = (List<string>)Session["test"];
```